# Determining imaginary axis crossing of a root locus

Tags: control-system, root-locus

I have an equation \begin{equation}{\text{L}\left(s\right)=\frac{K}{s(s+4)(s^2+6s+64)}} \end{equation}

and I am trying to determine it's root locus by hand.When I try plotting it with matlab, the root locus seems to cross the imaginary axis at about +/-5.06[image]

When I try to determine where the root locus will cross the imaginary axis by hand, I end up with two possible values for the imaginary axis crossing, either 5.06 like in the matlab plot or 3.52.
Is there some way of discarding a value for the imaginary axis crossing? Why do I end up with two values for the imaginary axis crossing but matlab only ends up with one?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed your manual calculations.

Answer (score 4):

In order to determine \$K\$. We need to investigate:

\$1+KF(s)=0\implies 1+L(s)=0 \implies s(s+4)(s^2+6s+64)+K=0.\$

We know that \$s=j\omega\$. Plugging this into the equation and collecting the real and imaginary part we obtain.

\$\left(10\omega^3-256\omega \right)+j\left(\omega^4-88\omega^2+K \right)=0+j\cdot 0\$

By comparing the complex number on the right and left-hand side of the equation we obtain two equations:

\$10\omega^3-256\omega=0 \qquad \wedge \qquad \omega^4-88\omega^2+K=0.\$

Solving the first equation leads to \$\omega=0, \omega=\pm\frac{8}{5}\sqrt{10}\$. \$ \omega =0 \$, would lead to the trivial solution \$ K=0\$. As the second equation is even both \$\omega=\pm\frac{8}{5}\sqrt{10}\approx5.060\$ lead to the same result  \$K=\frac{39936}{25}\approx1597.44\$, which is obvious because the root locus is symmetric with respect to the real axis.

Verifying this with MATLAB yields very similar results.

Comment: you are reversing the real and the imaginary parts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your calculation but Matlab yields the correct result. In this problem, the common approach is to use  **Routh-Hurwitz** criterion and search for  a row of zeros that yields the possibility for imaginary axis roots. For convert the system to the closed-loop transfer function, hence 
$$
\frac{K}{s^4 + 10s^3 + 88s^2 + 256s + K}
$$

The Routh table is

$$
\begin{matrix}
s^4 &&&& 1    &&&& 88  &&&& K \\
s^3 &&&& 10   &&&& 256  \\
s^2 &&&& 62.4 &&&& K    \\
s^1 &&&& \frac{15974.4-10K}{62.4}  \\
s^0 &&&& K 
\end{matrix}
$$

The \$ s^1 \$ row is the only row that can yield a row of zeros. From the preceding row, we obtain

$$
\begin{align}
&15974.4 - 10K = 0 \\
K &= \frac{15974.4}{10} = 1597.44
\end{align}
$$

Now we take a look at the row above \$s^1\$ and construct the following polynomial, hence

$$
\begin{align}
62.4 s^2 + K &= 0 \\
62.4 s^2 + 1597.44 &= 0 \\ 
s^2 &= \frac{-1597.44}{62.4} \\
s_{1,2} &= \pm j \sqrt{25.6} \\
s_{1,2} &= \pm j 5.0596 \\
\end{align}
$$

The root locus crosses the imaginary axis at \$\pm j5.0596\$ at the gain \$K=1597.44\$. Consequently, the gain \$K\$ must be less than 1597.44 for the system to be stable.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB is plotting the root locus only for positive values of \$K\$. Your analytical calculation may be considering both positive and negative values of \$K\$ and this is why you end up with two pair of points. Keep just the one that is obtained with \$K>0\$